# How to define the step size in plotting some graph in mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot some function . The code is given below.

```
f = 10000000;
v0 = 8.7;
T = 1*(1/f);
v[t] = v0*Sin[2*\[Pi]*f*t];
Plot[%, {t, 0, T} ]
```

Now the plot will make a plot of my function v[t] from 0 to T. What is the step size in this plotting ?
How to change this step size ?
What is by default step size?
Thanks

Comment: To obtain fixed stepsize, stick to `ListPlot[Table[{t, %}, {t, 0, T, T/(steps+1)}]]`.
Plot has options: `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursions` to control the mesh

Comment: "How to change this step size ? What is by default step size?" - that you ask this means you are not aware that *Mathematica* does something called *adaptive sampling* when it plots functions. Crudely stated, it means that *Mathematica* starts with an initial set of points (controlled by the `PlotPoints` option) and then keeps on refining it until the kinkiest parts of what it's plotting have been sufficiently sampled (controlled by `MaxRecursion` and the now-hidden option `MaxBend`).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Plot` with option combination `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` (as mentioned by @coolwater in the comments), or `DiscretePlot`:

```
ClearAll[v]
ff = 10000000; v0 = 8.7; T = 1*(1/ff);
v[t_] := v0*Sin[2*\[Pi]*ff*t];

plt1 = Plot[v[t], {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
plt2 = Plot[v[t], {t, 0, T}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[1, Red]];
plt3 = DiscretePlot[{v[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, T, T/9},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5, Orange], Thickness[.01]], 
   Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400, Filling -> None];

Legended[Show[plt1, plt3, plt2, ImageSize -> 500], 
 LineLegend[{Blue, Red, Orange}, Style[#, 20, "Palette"]&/@ {"Plot[v[t], {t, 0, T}]", 
    "Plot[v[t], {t, 0, T}, \nPlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0]", 
    "DiscretePlot[{v[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, T, T/9}]"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]